# Prevent memory error in itertools.permutation

Tags: python, python-itertools

Firstly I would like to mention that i have a 3 gb ram.

I am working on an algorithm that is exponential in time on the nodes so for it I have in the code

```
perm = list( itertools.permutations(list(graph.Nodes))) # graph.Nodes is a tuple of 1 , 2 , ... n integers
```

which generates all the combinations of vertices in a list and then i can work on one of the permutation.

However when i run the program for 40 vertices , it gives a memory error.

Is there any simpler way in implementation via which i can generate all the combinations of the vertices and not have this error.

Comment: As a sidebar, the reason for the memory error is this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40%21+bytes+in+gigabyte

Comment: `perm` would contain 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000 (40!) lists of 40 items.

Comment: Do you realize how many combinations of vertices there are? What are you going to do with all the combinations? You can avoid storing them all at once, but if you really need to consider every combination, the Universe is not guaranteed to exist by the time you are done... switching to C will not help, either.

Comment: What is the real algorithm - what are you trying to do? "exponential" time normally means O(2^N); here we have O(N!) which is much worse.

Comment: Yeah so i was working on some ordering problem which has no other solution till now :) ... anyways thanks a lots

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to use the iterator generated by the permutations instead of recreating a list with it :

```
perm_iterator = itertools.permutations(list(graph.Nodes))

for item in perm_iterator:
   do_the_stuff(item)
```

by doing this, python will keep in memory only the currently used permutation, not all the permutations (in term of memory usage, it is really better ;) )

On the other side, once the memory problem solved, the time to treat all the permutations will be growing exponentially with the number of vertices....

Answer (score 4):

It won't work. Looping over an iterator won't work either. You see, if the code in the for-loop takes 1 microsecond to run, it will take 2.587×10^34 years to run completely. (See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40%21+microseconds+in+years)