# Python OOM error while shuffling itertools.permutation(range(15))

Tags: python, permutation

Of the 15! possible permutations of the digits 1-15, I need to select 10! of them at random.

Unfortunately, while the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503429/1130698) avoids the out-of-memory issue encountered when storing all of the permutations and shuffling them, if I iterate over the first 10! permutations using the iterator returned by itertools.permutations they will all be in order. It's important for me to obtain a random sampling of the permutations (with no duplicates).

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import shuffle
from math import factorial

count=15
placements = list(permutations(range(count), count))
shuffle(placements)
for placement in placements[:factorial(10)]:
    // do something with placement
```

I tried the following but there's no guarantee it won't select the same permutation twice:

```
from math import factorial
from random import sample

count=15
for notused in range(factorial(10)):
    placement = sample(range(count),count)
    \\ do something with placement
```

Currently trying following approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982711/1130698):

```
from math import factorial
from random import sample

placements = set()
count = 15
cap = factorial(10)
while len(placements) < cap:
    placements.add(tuple(sample(range(count),count)))
for placement in placements:
    \\ do something with placement
```

Comment: Or, just do what industry does and use a heuristic?

Comment: could you provide a recommendation in this particular case?

Comment: I was able to store 10! integers in a list. I'm working on something based on 1) select, 2) prune, 3) shuffle. It might help if you post the code for the progress you made.

Comment: I'm also able to store 10! integers in a list but count may be as high as 30 in my application. I tried the following but there's no guarantee it won't select the same permutation twice:
<added to original post because code formatting>

Comment: You can add stuff to the original question with the edit button directly below it, and above the comments. If it can have a 30 character alphabet, you need a new approach. Maybe one with the chance of a duplicate every now and then.

Comment: Do you have to use `python`?

Comment: If I didn't have to use python, what would you recommend and why?

Comment: There are a couple of packages (`arrangements` and `RcppAlgos` (I am the author)) in `R` that are built for this type of thing. For example, `placements = RcppAlgos::permuteSample(15, 15, n = factorial(10), seed = 42))` produces your desired output in just over 3 seconds.

Comment: interesting, if it were worth converting the codebase to R I would have used this approach. However, because this is not a real-time operation the last code sample in the question seems to serve my needs. thanks for sharing and authoring

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, permutations in your case is basically shuffling the list in a way that no number repeats, may be you can do:

```
from random import shuffle
samps = []
count = 0
while count < 10:

    j = list(range(15))
    shuffle(j)
    if j not in samps:
        samps.append(j)
    count += 1
```

This gives:

```
[[0, 11, 13, 14, 1, 9, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 10, 2, 12, 8],
 [10, 1, 9, 2, 4, 0, 13, 14, 5, 8, 12, 7, 11, 3, 6],
 [3, 13, 6, 4, 12, 5, 0, 2, 10, 7, 1, 8, 11, 9, 14],
 [1, 10, 13, 7, 11, 9, 8, 4, 14, 0, 12, 2, 3, 6, 5],
 [9, 8, 7, 11, 3, 10, 6, 5, 4, 0, 14, 12, 1, 13, 2],
 [3, 11, 6, 8, 1, 4, 12, 14, 7, 5, 13, 0, 10, 9, 2],
 [5, 13, 8, 3, 0, 9, 1, 4, 11, 12, 6, 14, 2, 10, 7],
 [11, 1, 0, 2, 13, 12, 14, 3, 6, 10, 9, 7, 4, 8, 5],
 [12, 10, 6, 7, 2, 13, 3, 0, 1, 8, 4, 11, 14, 5, 9],
 [2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 12, 14, 6, 3, 10, 8, 13, 11, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I expect this to give the memory error if you use factorial(10) instead of 10, but I ran it anyway. It is only up to 64000 iterations after one minute, where I killed it. The performance will degrade rapidly after that because "in" is an O(n) operation. You might consider a set, and them maybe you will get the memory error. But you can't use lists -- you need a hashable type.

Comment: Added approach to the question based on Kenny's feedback on YOLO's suggestion

Comment: @Danny isn't it what you need ? if not, why?

Comment: While I believe this will work, I am testing the runtime. I am expecting ~15 minutes on i7-7700k based on the results of my processing when running with count = factorial(10). It's unknown how often shuffle will produce a permutation already in the set (creating needless work)

Comment: This was stuck in an infinite loop because the set.add() failed silenty trying to add a list(). updated the question to show the use of tuple. this enumeration of permutations now takes 1 min 20 sec

Comment: @Danny I am using list. How long it takes using my answer ?