# Itertools combination Memory error with Python

Tags: python

I have a Memory error when I use combinations with a big list of list like len 735.
Any way to do a similar process but without the error?

```
from itertools import combinations

valores = [[5, 10.732544898986816], [9, 10.596251487731934], [11, 10.70582103729248]]
f = list(combinations(valores, 3))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: Don't make a list out of it, that's the **whole point** of itertools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent memory error in itertools.permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503388/prevent-memory-error-in-itertools-permutation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list has 735 elements, then there are (735 choose 3) = 65907695 combinations of three elements. There is probably no need to keep all of these 3-tuples in memory at the same time, so don't build a list out of them; just iterate directly.

```py
for c in combinations(valores, 3):
    # do something with c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to prevent memory error.

```
comb_iter = itertools.combinations(valores,3)

for item in comb_iter:
   do_the_stuff(item)
```

As a result, python will keep in memory only the currently used combination, not all the combinations.